# how to gather several fields from linked data in one query?

Tags: orientdb

I have a graph db with Members and Pages, some members can be ExpertOf some pages. I am trying to build a query giving experts of a given page, with all the pages they are experts of.

To sum up, I have a simple db : Member---(ExpertOf)--->Page

My (quite) working query is

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf') AS expertises FROM
    (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```

It works as expected, returning :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:0",
            "@version": 0,
            "rid": "#17:0",
            "title": "John Doe",
            "expertises": [
                "#16:299",
                "#16:221",
                "#15:160",
                "#16:94",
                "#16:714"
            ],
            "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,expertises=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.057 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

(btw, I wonder what is this @rid:#-2:0...)

But now, instead of having pages @rid, I would like to have both @rid and title...

I've tried :

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf').title AS expertises FROM
    (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```

or (same result)

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf').include('title') AS expertises FROM
    (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```

which gives :

```
    "expertises": [
          "Wave on string",
          "USE A SLOPE",
          "Spin coating",
          "Gas hydrate",
          "Mpemba effect"
    ],
```

then

```
SELECT @rid,title, out('ExpertOf').include('@rid','title') AS
expertises FROM (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```

which returns :

```
    "expertises": [
        "#16:299",
        "#16:221",
        "#15:160",
        "#16:94",
        "#16:714"
    ],
```

whereas I would have hoped

```
    "expertises": [
        { "@rid":"#16:299", "title":"Wave on string" },
        { "@rid":"#16:221", "title":"USE A SLOPE" },
        { "@rid":"#15:160", "title":"Spin coating" },
        { "@rid":"#16:94", "title":"Gas hydrate" },
        { "@rid":"#16:714", "title":"Mpemba effect" }
    ],
```

I've tried `expand(out('ExpertOf').include('@rid','title'))` or `unwind expertises`, or `unionAll(out('ExpertOf').@rid,out('ExpertOf').title)` as explained elsewhere, and so on... but no query has given the hoped result.

Is there a way to get this kind of result ? (I've succeded to make it work with a function calling a query on Page, but I am wondering if this can be done in one query, and if my solution is efficient).

Thanks

Comment: The negative rid is caused by you using projection, and therefore creating temporary document, at least I think so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTP and you want to obtain a nested JSON, you can use fetchplans:

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf') AS expertises FROM
  (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
fetchplan *:0 expertises.rid:1 expertises.title:1 expertises:-2
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it works, but doesn't return the 'title' field.

Comment: "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:0",
            "@version": 0,
            "rid": "#17:0",
            "title": "John Doe",
            "expertises": [
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@rid": "#16:299",
                    "@version": 5,
                    "@class": "Page"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@rid": "#16:221",
                    "@version": 6,
                    "@class": "Page"
                }, ...

Comment: That's quite strange, I tried on a dataset locally and it works fine. If you have a script to reproduce your case I can try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

instead of this,

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf').include('title') AS expertises FROM
    (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```

try to do this one

```
SELECT @rid,title,out('ExpertOf')['title'] AS expertises FROM
    (SELECT expand(in('ExpertOf')) FROM Page WHERE @rid=16:299)
```